# Redux : useSelector returns undefined but returns data at 3 rd time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting the data from the api as expected but the problem here is I am getting it in a 3rd attempt which is causing the error in my application when there's no data to show.

I am testing it printing on a console but it's the same error. As Soon As I Refresh My Page The Error Comes Flooding In The Console

[image: The Error]

**Reducer**

```
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { products: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        product: action.payload,
      };

    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Component**

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, alert, error]);

  console.log(product);
```

**Action**

```
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container container-fluid">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the loading in the initial state I think that's why

`export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { products: {} }, action) => {`

you are trying to access the loading state before you set the value of the state that's why you are getting the error
you should set the loading and error in the initial state with the default values

`const initialState = {products: {}, loading: true, error: null}`

and then pass it to the reducer.

`export const productDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {`

and change the product into products

hopefully, this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and I think the problem is with your initial state in

```
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { products: {} }, action) =>
```

try changing `state={products:{}}` with `state={product: {}}`